# Make GPS in Minecraft Vanilla

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to make some kind of GPS which tells you which direction you need to go?
Here is a picture of an example:
[image]

Imagine that the lines are streets and when you are in point A, you want to go to point B, but you don't know how to get there. It would be helpful if it says things like "Go left" and "Go right". But how are you going to make this?

Comment: I mean, you can already determine where you are in the world by coordinates, and you can craft a map which acts in this way, but there's no way to really do turn-by-turn navigation or anything like that

Comment: You could use command blocks, I'm not a professional but I think you can use Redstone to tell when a player approaches an area to trigger a command block to have text pop up on the player's screen. This is purely static though, meaning the path/destination cannot change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible and i will show you how to do it in steps

1. You need to have access to a map dont do anything to the map yet dont right click it
2. Ok this will require a little bit of building stack up blocks to a tall hight
3. Now place the blocks of your choice in the directions to the places where you want them to go
4. You are done! if you have any questions ask me
5. The only problems are that you have to put the road/map in a single chunk or else half will be off the map and half will be on another map or it will require alot of building

Answer (score -2):

I have saw a video on YouTube before that has your answer. It is "Yes".
By: **SethBling**.
Publish Date: **8-14-2014**.
[Click here  to go to the YouTube video!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1lQpf-Xjyc)

Comment: Please summarize the information contained in the video.  That way, if ever the video goes down, your answer is still valid.